# Does the BCM43438 WiFi chip in Raspberry Pi 3 support "monitor" mode

Tags: wifi

Does it support the monitor mode (known from aircrack-ng & co.)?

Comment: You've listed the wrong chip. The Pi 3 uses a BCM43438, *not* a BCM43143.

Comment: Good to know. So it seems to be a wrong product description ...

Comment: No idea - where did you get your description from?

Comment: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2020826.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But there are [plans to try and implement it](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211) apparently

**EDIT:**(should this be related to BCM43143, once the smoke clears around the BCM chip number this might become a full on "NO".)

Comment: [Looks like a 'no' then unfortunately](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Radiospec.png), although I'd still like to try and confirm that somehow. Tricky with no datasheet! I notice there's a wearable prototyping platform called the [Ingenic Newton2](http://www.cnx-software.com/2014/11/13/ingenic-unveils-newton2-platform-for-wearables-with-m200-dual-core-soc/) that uses the same chip. Could be some clues there.

Answer (score 19):

The firmware used in the BCM4339 (Nexus 5) as well as the BCM43438 (RPI3) got a **built-in monitor mode**.

We just recently discovered this functionality after implementing the monitor mode for the Nexus 5 (see: [nexmon.org](http://nexmon.org)). The default firmware at least already supports emitting raw 802.11 frames. You can use a unmodified firmware and just send the IOCTLs `108` and `10` from the driver to the firmware. You also have to change the interface type.

We currently still working on improving the monitor mode for the Raspberry Pi 3, but we already got a dd'able image ready for your SD card, have a look at: [rpi3.nexmon.org](http://rpi3.nexmon.org). In the current version we extended the built-in monitor mode to generate frames encapsulated in a Radiotap header.

**Update:**
Thanks @user1147688, the links above should also be updated :-)

Comment: The github for making the kernel patch using the RPi3 `nexmon` is [here](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/bcm-rpi3).

Answer (score 1):

no, i get this error

Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :

Comment: You got this error doing what exactly? What makes you believe the error is due to the lack of hardware features rather than your actions?

Comment: You receive this error in response to `sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor` as the default driver in Raspbian (to this day) relies on a non-free firmware and/or driver/module which do not have monitor mode support. The alternative is to patch/hack the official driver. Worth noting, however, that it's actually less hassle to grab a wifi adapter that has proper monitor mode support in the driver (and firmware), they are dirt cheap these days, about the size of an OTP adapter, and they work consistently -- getting things like `nexmon` to consistently build over time? *shakes magic 8-ball*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and I am very happy with the nexmon project that has enabled this.

I've created the following script that automates the directions on the NEXMON project.
Nexmon, what a great project.

The following script will detect if it is run on a pi-zerow, Pi3 or Pi3b+ and compile
and apply the relative patch. It even preserves the patch on reboot of the device.

https://github.com/zorani/RaspPiNexmonScripts

Enjoy!