# Kali Linux Wifi Monitor Mode

Tags: usb, wifi

I have installed **Kali Linux** on my **Raspberry PI2 Model B**. I have also bought **Raspberry PI USB Wi-Fi Dongle**. When I try to put the adaptor into **"monitor mode"** using *airmon-ng start wlan0* I get an error (ERROR adding monitor mode interface: command failed: Operation not supported (-95)). What can I do to fix it (buy a different one or something else) ?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please be more concise with the title. The "on RPi" is not helping, as everything here is suppossed to be on the Pi. Instead try to include a very short statement of the problem, something along the line *WiFi monitor mode not working, something, something*. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The Raspberry-Pi Wi-Fi adapter is based on the **BCM43143** ([official product description](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/usb-wifi-dongle/)) chipset which does not support monitor mode with current drivers. (as written [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43425/does-the-bcm43438-wifi-chip-in-raspberry-pi-3-support-monitor-mode)).

Answer (score 2):

You should try a USB WiFi Dongle that has the supporting chip-set.
Then install required drivers , then use airmon-ng. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for different wifi dongles this one fall in the category of good and affordable: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0035OCVO6?m=A5PVPB4WB2LS4&ref_=v_sp_detail_page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035OCVO6)