# Radiotap headers and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian

I am new to this area and hence the question.

I want to have Radiotap headers in the network data captures with Wireshark. I wonder if that is even possible in this case:

Configuration: Raspberry Pi 3 (Canakit), Combo wifi/bluetooth/FM: BCM43438 or CYW43438 (direct board-level integration with antenna), Raspbian Jessie OS

If not, do I need to get a different NIC? What are the options?

Answer (score 0):

In order use Wireshark to capture packets,the interface has to be set in Monitor mode.

See if this posting helps

[Does the BCM43438 WiFi chip in Raspberry Pi 3 support "monitor" mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43425/does-the-bcm43438-wifi-chip-in-raspberry-pi-3-support-monitor-mode)

Vittal