# Not able to close monitor mode in my Raspberry PI0W

Tags: kali

I decided to start monitor mode on my Raspberry PI0 but I messed up somethings afterwards and decided to reinstall kali linux but after reinstalling it I was not able to connect to the internet and when I checked for wifi adapters using `ifconfig` I saw 3 devices there-1)lo 2)wlan0 3)mon.wlan0
I looked up the internet for solutions and found out that I would have to close monitor mode to connect to internet but I am not able to do so as its a fresh installation. `iwconfig wlan0 mode managed` doesn't work. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question you want to enable monitor mode on your wifi device. With *kali linux* I cannot help you because I don't use it. But the wifi device on your RasPi must support monitor mode in general. As far as I know all wifi devices on the RasPis have similar options. I don't have a RPi0W but on my RasPi 3B+ I find this modes:

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

There is no monitor mode supported and I don't believe it is supported on a RPi0W. Check it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo iw list
```

You will get a bunch of information. Look at the *Supported interface modes*. If you do not find **monitor** then you are lost. You have to buy an USB wifi dongle that supports monitor mode. For example my dongle shows this:

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
```

**UPDATE:**
I have found this answer to [Does the BCM43438 WiFi chip in Raspberry Pi 3 support “monitor” mode](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54660/79866). With the [nexmon](https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon) project it is possible to patch the firmware for the wifi chip to use monitor mode and other extensions but you have to compile the driver.